# Oracle incompatible driver ORA-12650

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, spring-jdbc, ojdbc

We try to upgrade our web application database from **Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0) to Oracle 19c (19.0.0.0.0)**, but I'm encountering the error **ORA-12650** with the following stack trace in `catalina.log`:

```
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650)
Oct 06, 2023 9:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive marcofeed.war
Oct 06, 2023 9:10:22 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:140)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:793)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1028)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:637)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:238)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 37 more
```

Our stack:

- Spring Framework 4.0.6.RELEASE
- Tomcat 6.0.39
- JDK 1.8.0_65-b17
- ojdbc6 11.2.0.4

I found that it's a problem of compatibility (as per https://www.oracle.com/fr/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) so I upgraded the dependencies, but I encounter the same issue:

- Spring Framework 4.2.0.RELEASE
- Tomcat 6.0.39
- JDK 1.8.0_65-b17
- ojdbc8 12.2.0.1

Taken from the above docs:

[image]
[image]

Moreover, I tried to upgrade the ojdbc8 driver to some other new versions(18.3.0.0, 19.3.0.0), but still have the same problem

In pom.xml, I have the following related dependencies:

```
    <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Have you encountered the same issue? Can it be related to the tomcat server?

**EDIT**

1. We cannot change the database version
2. One application which runs on Spring Boot 2.0.7 with ojdbc8 12.2.0.1 successfully integrated with the oracle database without encountering this problem

Comment: Have you searched the error code? Which indicates incompatible encodings being used.

Comment: This error code is related to a compatibility problem with Native Network Encryption. Which version of the DB are you using? Also 19.3 is old. You should try 19.20: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html

Comment: The database version is 19.0.0.0.0 (taken from SELECT * from v$version). I also updated the question with these details

Comment: @M. Deinum The error code states that there is no such common encryption algorithm between de database and the connector (as per community.boomi.com/s/article/…). Also, I need to mention that another application that runs on Spring Boot 2.0.7 successfully migrated to this database without any issue (ojdbc8 12.2.0.1), so there shouldn't be a problem with the database

Comment: You need to use a newer JDBC driver version than 11.2.0.4... preferably the latest version.

Comment: Where do I state it is an issue with the database that is your assumption. The problem is more like your JDK which doesn't have certain encryption algorithms enabled or shipped. Make sure you are using the most recent JDK8 version and that it has/comes with the proper encryptions or add an external library for those encryptions or (even better) migrate to JDK11 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It seems that there was a **different incompatible** `odjbc14.jar` in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` that was taken into consideration instead of the one from the maven repo path. I removed it manually and copied the good one (`ojdbc8.jar` 12.2.0.1) there and the issue was solved